# HTML5 Drag and Drop - Firefox is being redirected

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement HTML5's drag and drop in my app, but Firefox is always redirected to dropped image's source. I'm using `e.stopPropagation()`. In Chromium everything works as expected.
Here's the code:

```html
<section class="desktop">
  <img class="icon" style="left: 0px; top: 340px;" src="./computer.png" />
  <img class="icon" style="left: 0px; top: 170px;" src="./documents.png" />
  <img class="icon" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;" src="./bin.png" />
</section>
<script>
  window.clickedIcons = [];
  window.draggedIcon = {
    offset: [0, 0],
    element: null
  };

  //Drag & drop
  function dragStart(e) {
    window.draggedIcon.element = e.target;
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copyMove';
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'hey'); //hack

    const style = getComputedStyle(event.target);
    draggedIcon.element = event.target;
    draggedIcon.offset[0] =
        parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left")) - event.clientX;
    draggedIcon.offset[1] =
        parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top" )) - event.clientY;
  }

  function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
       
  function drop(e) {
    draggedIcon.element.style.left =
        (event.clientX + window.draggedIcon.offset[0]) + 'px';
    draggedIcon.element.style.top =
        (event.clientY + window.draggedIcon.offset[1]) + 'px';
    draggedIcon.element.style.visibility = 'visible';
    draggedIcon.element = null;

    if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    return false;
  }

  const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.desktop .icon');
  for (const i of icons) {
    i.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
    i.addEventListener('click', click, false);
  }

  document.body.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, true);
  document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, true);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to [prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
function drop(e) {
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
    if(e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    window.draggedIcon.element.style.left = (event.clientX + window.draggedIcon.offset[0]) + 'px';
    window.draggedIcon.element.style.top  = (event.clientY + window.draggedIcon.offset[1]) + 'px';
    window.draggedIcon.element.style.visibility = 'visible';
    window.draggedIcon.element = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `preventDefault` does the job ! But could someone explain me why a drop would trigger a redirect on Firefox ??

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Wild guess: Dropping a file into Firefox navigates to the file, that's why the default is navigate to the URL being dropped. In my case, `drag` had called `event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', "css")` before and FF attempted to open the URL `"css"`.