# Why doesn't HTML5 drag and drop work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have bound events to different elements, and when I drag them in all browsers, except Firefox, it works as expected. In firefox, however, it doesn't work at all. The only event that fires is `dragstart`, and none of the other events fire. What's going on?

Comment: Example code and Firefox version please?

Comment: It was supposed to post the answer at the same time but it didn't.... not sure why.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm not using jQuery, so removed the `originalEvent` portion and changed the format to text (or IE had issues), and it works:

```js
event.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'anything');
```

In the drop event make sure to call:

```js
event.preventDefault();
```

Or it will jump to anything.com.

Comment: with `event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', 'anything')` it will not jump to anything.com

Comment: for anyone else fighting with drag and drop on FF, this will probably be relevant to you as well, though unrelated to this particular issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656061/event-clientx-showing-as-0-in-firefox-for-dragend-event

Comment: Also, you need to specifically make sure you call preventDefault() on your drop event handler to prevent it from trying to navigate. Not sure what Mozilla was thinking when they did this awful implementation.

Answer (score 34):

Firefox requires that a user run the `dataTransfer.setData` function in the event.

For you `jQuery` users, that means the following code should resolve your issue:

```
function dragstartHandler(event){

  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

}
```

Future events on the same drag will now properly fire as you expected. Obviously you can replace the `setData` arguments with more useful data.

Comment: Use 'text' instead of 'text/plain' if you want it to work in IE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803235/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-ie-javascript-html5

Comment: This works, but as of today, the MDN Drag documentation still says that a DragEvent has a dataTransfer property. No mention of having to reference originalEvent.

Comment: @LexLindsey, the originalEvent is for jQuery as indicated in the answer.

Comment: So it is a bug in Firefox that force you to set a data on drag-start event.

Comment: it works for me in React by `event.nativeEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'anything')` in `onDragStart` prop.

Answer (score 6):

FF has long-standing issues with eating certain mouse events that originate from elements that have overflow set to auto or scroll.

In my case, I had a well-used library for drag and drop that worked perfectly in the samples and in my app on every browser but Firefox. After digging through the tickets related to this, I found a solution that I fully credit to a contributor to [this ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339293)

which is to set

```
-moz-user-select: none
```

on the scrolled element being dragged from. It solved my particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as a reference for this question solution regarding the redirects that occur on Firefox.

You need to prevent the default action in drop method to fix this issue.

```
function drop(e) {
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
    if(e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }

    //your code here

    return false;
}
```

I got this solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14542233/5672812).

Answer (score 1):

use this

IE:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
```

Firefox:

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '');
```

Comment: This enables me the `dragend` event, but `drag` events still not working on firefox.

Comment: drag event still not working for me too.