# Why doesn't the '@drop' event work for me in vue?

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, dom-events, drop, vue-events

The `@drop` listener doesn't work for me. It doesn't call the method I'm telling it to call.

I want to drag the chip and be able to drop it on another component, and perform a function, but at the time of dropping the chip, the `dropLink` method is not executed, so I assume that the `@drop` event is not emitted.

No errors are displayed on the console.

The rest of the events do work well, like `@dragstart`.

This is the code of the component I use:

```html
<template>
  <div
    @keydown="preventKey"
    @drop="dropLink"
  >
    <template
      v-if="!article.isIndex"
    >
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-chip
            small
            draggable
            class="float-left mt-2"
            v-on="on"
            @dragstart="dragChipToLinkToAnotherElement"
          >
            <v-icon x-small>
              mdi-vector-link
            </v-icon>
          </v-chip>
        </template>
        <span>Link</span>
      </v-tooltip>

      <v-chip-group
        class="mb-n2"
        show-arrows
      >
        <v-chip
          v-for="(lk, index) in links"
          :key="index"
          small
          outlined
          :class="{'ml-auto': index === 0}"
        >
          {{ lk.text }}
        </v-chip>
      </v-chip-group>
    </template>

    <div
      :id="article.id"
      spellcheck="false"
      @mouseup="mouseUp($event, article)"
      v-html="article.con"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ItemArticle',
  props: {
    article: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    links () {
      return this.article.links
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mouseUp (event, article) {
      this.$emit('mouseUp', { event, article })
    },
    preventKey (keydown) {
      this.$emit('preventKey', keydown)
    },
    dragChipToLinkToAnotherElement (event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.article.id)
    },
    dropLink (e) {
      //but this method is never called
      console.log('evento drop is ok', e)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the project I am also using Nuxt in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 58):

In order to make the `div` a drop target, the [`div`'s `dragenter` and `dragover` events must be canceled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#droptargets). Firefox also [needs the `drop` event to be canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541775/html5-drag-and-drop-firefox-is-being-redirected).

You can invoke [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on those events with the `.prevent` [event modifier](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers):

```html
<div @drop.prevent="dropLink" @dragenter.prevent @dragover.prevent></div>
```

If you need to accept/reject drops based on the drag data type, set a handler that conditionally calls `Event.preventDefault()`:

```html
<div @drop.prevent="dropLink" @dragenter="checkDrop" @dragover="checkDrop"></div>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    checkDrop(e) {
      if (/* allowed data type */) {
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-wave-3mz7d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FItemArticle.vue&theme=dark)