# Drop Event not executing sometimes in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop

`Update`:
I found that the drop event would not be called everytime I dragged my entry over the div element with class `dateTitle`. Trying to figure out why.

`Original`

I am working on a Todo list to drag items to different lists. To do this, I am using the `drop`, `dragstart`, and `dragend` events. For the most part, this is working fine when I drag to other lists or the same list.

My issue is that when I drop an entry in the same list, sometimes it will not call the `drop` function which leads to only the `dragend` function being called. The way I have my app set up, I need the drop function to fire successfully every time to ensure everything is in order.

It happens mostly when I drag and drop really quick in the same list.

`Gif`

[image: Example]

`Console`

[image: Console Logs]

`List`

```js
<template>
  <div @drop="onDrop()">
    <div class="dateTitle">
      {{ dayNumber }}
    </div>
   <!-- Items go here-->
    <Entry v-for="entry in entries" @dragstart="dragStart()" @dragend="dragEnd()" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

 components: {
   Entry
 },

 data() {
       return { entries = [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...etc], sameList: false   }
 },

 methods: {
    onDrop() {
         // this needs to execute everytime!
          console.log("DROP");
          if (//if dropping in the same list dont continue) {
           console.log("Same List");
           this.sameList = true;
           return 
          }
          

     },
    dragStart() { 
          // this executes without fail
      console.log("================");
      console.log("DRAG START");
     },
    dragEnd() {
          // this executes without fail, except it doesnt work as appropriately if onDrop isnt called.
          console.log("DRAG END");
          if (this.sameList) return;
          
         }
  }
}
<script/>
```

Comment: Try using `dragend.prevent`

Comment: The only thing is that I need dragend in my Entry as a cleanup function.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63066729/11545271

Comment: Thanks for the help! That worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the '@drop' event work for me in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063312/why-doesnt-the-drop-event-work-for-me-in-vue)